# How to Hide Address Bar in Svelte.js Website?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm developing a Svelte.js website and want to maximize screen space by hiding the address bar. Are there specific meta tags or Svelte techniques to achieve this? appreciate any advice.

Thanks!

developing a Svelte.js website

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Most if not all modern browser will not allow this for security reasons (the user should be able to tell where they are).

The only thing you can do is [go into fullscreen mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullscreen), which will take up the entire screen and might also be blocked by the user via settings.